# Google Chrome Blue Screen

Tags: google-chrome

I am experiencing this problem of Chrome getting blue screen, which usually happens when GMail is opened in one of the tabs. Once it starts appearing blue, then Chrome needs to be re-opened for proper working. Any solution to this problem?

Here is a screenshot of my problem -
[image: Chrome - Frozen Window - Blue Screen]
[image: Task Manager in Google Chrome]

Comment: Which version of Chrome? When does this happen? As soon as you open GMail or when you perform some action? Does this happen in an incognito tab as well, where hopefully most of your extensions are disabled?

Comment: I am using the current stable version of chrome 27.
This happens in incoginto tab as well but not as soon as I open GMail, happens after some time. I guess incoginto has all extensions disabled.. So, I believe there is nothing wrong with extensions.